# SQL Multiply Columns in where statment

Tags: sql

I am newer to sql I have a table:

### MyTable

```
column1  column2
-----------------
5        3 
2        2
```

I need a query that will give me back all of the rows `where column1 * column2 > 10`?

Comment: You need to filter using the HAVING keyword, if your SQL supports it. You don't mention which version you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT *   FROM MyTable   WHERE (column1 * column2) > 10;`
You can specify as many columns as you want (within reason) and apply math to them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: True, but it makes it slightly more readable, and always putting them in comes in handy when you have many columns.

Comment: But depending on context, a missing bracket can really screw with results because it might not trigger a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks that is simpler than I thought it would be. And Thanks for helping me format the question OMG Ponies

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1, column2
from MyTable
where column1 * column2 > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can do this in the where clause ie select * from mytable where column1*column2 > 10

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MyTable where Column1 * Column2 > 10
```